# Is there something wrong with my Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

Recently I was trying to run a simple example of library QUESO, here is the information about the library:

http://www.quest-scidac.org/software/queso/

I followed the user manual to write my own Makefile and try to run the example, this is my Makefie:

```
QUESO_DIR = /project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1
BOOST_DIR = /share/apps/boost-1.57
GSL_DIR = /project/cacds/apps/gsl/1.16

INC_PATHS = -I$(QUESO_DIR)/include -I$(BOOST_DIR)/include/boost -I$(GSL_DIR)/include/gsl

LIBS = \
-L$(QUESO_DIR)/lib -lqueso \
-L$(BOOST_DIR)/lib -lboost_program_options \
-L$(GSL_DIR)/lib -lgsl 

CXX = mpic++
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -c

default : all
.SUFFIXES : .o .C
all : example_sip
clean :
    rm -f *~
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f simple_sip_example

example_sip : example_main.o example_likelihood.o example_compute.o
    $(CXX) example_main.o \
           example_likelihood.o \
           example_compute.o \
           -o simple_sip_example $(LIBS)
%.o: %.C
    $(CXX) $(INC_PATHS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<
```

This is the Makefile on the user manual:
[image]

I followed the user manual and only changed the library path. But when I type `make -f Makefile_1`, I got these errors:

```
mpic++ -I/project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/include -I/share/apps/boost-1.57/include/boost 
-I/project/cacds/apps/gsl/1.16/include/gsl -g -Wall -c 
-L/project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/lib -lqueso -L/share/apps/boost-1.57/lib 
-lboost_program_options -L/project/cacds/apps/gsl/1.16/lib -lgsl  example_main.C
In file included from /project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/include/queso/Environment.h:38,
             from example_compute.h:28,
             from example_main.C:25:
/project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/include/queso/ScopedPtr.h:44: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'unique_ptr' with no type
/project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/include/queso/ScopedPtr.h:44: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
/project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/include/queso/ScopedPtr.h:44: error: expected ';' before '<' token
In file included from example_compute.h:28,
             from example_main.C:25:
/project/xfu/apps/queso-0.56.1/include/queso/Environment.h:380: error: 'Type' in class 'QUESO::ScopedPtr<QUESO::GetPot>' does not name a type
make: *** [example_main.o] Error 1
```

You can see these errors came from the header file of the library. Source file is from the library, I only wrote the Makefile. I run this example in a school cluster, there shouldn't be any problem on the library because the IT installed it. So I guess the problem may come from my Makefile, but I just followed the user manual. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: You didn't follow the example, you added the `$(LIBS)` in the `%.o`

Comment: It might be that the error is really in your code, if you wrote "bad stuff" before the `#include <ScopedPtr.h>` then your code could be impacting the standard header.  For example if you used `#define` on some common symbol that `ScopedPtr.h` wants, etc.  There's no way to tell from the question asked here, what the problem really is.

Comment: @cpatricio Oh yes, thank you for pointing out, but it's the same even I delete `$(LIBS)` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved. It's because of the C++11 standard.
It seems that QUESO was built with C++11 by default, but my gcc version didn't support C++11. After updating gcc and rebuilt the library, make sure using `-std=c++11`, there is no such problem.